# How to integrate Google API Client library with Django Rest Framework

Tags: android, python, django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to implement authentication between the Android client and  Django Rest Framework server. I finally settled on [this method](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth).

Now I would like to know how to integrate [Google's API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library) with Django Rest Framework.

Specifically, how do I create the `requests.Request()` object in Django Rest Framework?

Answer (score 0):

DRF's request class api: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/.
The example about how to make a request and repsonse: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/. Back to your question on how to integrate Google API Libray with DRF, Google client is the client who make the request to the DRF server. So you should look at the google api library on how to make a request. And DRF is the server who handle the request.Basically in the views.py, you either use request.POST(post data to the endpoint) or request.data(handles arbitrary data) to handle the data you make the request in the google client. Sometimes you need to serialize the data making it a json format. Hope this answer your question.